# How to adjust Intellisense in the Visual Studio 2022 to display specific class member in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, intellisense

If we look at default std::wstring, the Intellisense in VS 2022 displays the contents of a string if I mouse over it:

[image]

I've written my own class, but is there a way to tell Intellisense which member of that class to display in the Intellisense popup during a mouse-over for? Because otherwise it displays the info that is not very useful:

[image]

In this case I would like it to display a value (cast to PCWSTR) from a derived class. Is such possible?

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/create-custom-views-of-native-objects?view=vs-2022